# Prevalence / Incidence and Relative Risk

Tags: relative-risk, incidence-rate-ratio, prevalence

I'm doing a course in biostatistics and I came across this question to solve:

"Consider a two-year follow-up study of the association between a measure
of stress (dichotomised into two levels: high and low) and high blood pressure (D, dichotomised into two levels: normal and high). In the study, participants were treated at
the appearance of high blood pressure to attempt to return the levels to normal ones. It was
noted that the relative risk for high blood pressure, associated with a high stress level, was
two if incidence of D, during follow-up, was used as the outcome, but four if prevalence
of D at the end of the study was used as an alternative outcome. Qualitatively explain this
discrepancy"

I tried to solve it but I don't know if my logic it's correct on on the right path. I think I should answer it considering that prevalence takes into account old and new cases and that RR is higher giving prevalence as an outcome for other reasons such as the "disease" takes time to be " cured". I appreciate any thoughts on it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There isn't a *lot* of detail to go on (such problems have a tendency to be under-specified) but I'd think the clue is that incidence means "occurrence of D at any point in the study" whereas prevalence is "actively has D at the end of the study".